# How to make a thick black border on an hyperlink?

Tags: html, css

How to implement thick black border to the following `Read more` hyperlink ? I used `style="border-color: blue important !;"` .But its not working. so that it looks like a thick black border surrounded to the link.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
a:link, a:visited {
    display: block;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #ffffff;
    background-color: #98bf21;
    width: 120px;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 4px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover, a:active {
    background-color: #7A991A;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<a href="default.asp" target="_blank">Read More</a>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: at first it is not `important !` it is `!important`

Comment: at second blue is not black

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to set up border width and border style:

```css
a {
  /* border: 5px solid black; */
  border-width: 5px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: black;

  padding: 2px 5px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">LINK</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

It should be:

`style="border: 3px solid black;"`

Answer (score 1):

Use below code:

```
border: 5px solid blue;
```

Comment: He says.. black not blue :P

Comment: @Lipis no problem ;-)

Comment: @Amitsingh I think it's because of six almost identical answers

Comment: I am not suprised, some of stack-overflow users abuse their downvoting rights, they just downvote for no reason

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
a{
 border: 3px solid #000; //You can play with the size.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

just add

```
style="border: 2px solid blue;"
```

And you can also do like this

```
style="border: 2px solid blue!important;"
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't have any specifications for thickness.
refactor your code & Try this

```css
//px indicates the thickness of the border
a {
  border: 3px solid black;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please refer following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
     <style>
        a:link, a:visited {
        display: block;
        font-weight: bold;
        color: #ffffff;
        background-color: #98bf21;
        width: 120px;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 5px;

        }
      a{
       border-style: solid;
        border-width: 5px;
        border-color:black;
    }

        a:hover, a:active {
        background-color: #7A991A;
        }
        </style>
        <a href="default.asp" target="_blank">Read More</a>
    </body>
    </html>
```